# Java Android - ListView Layout problems

Tags: java, android, listview

I want to show the comments on the page, created a layout:
(ListView, at the very end. At the beginning of this information about this post).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="71dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lineradapter"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp">

    <FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout1" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="6dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|left"
        android:fontFamily="normal"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:textColor="#525252"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:fontFamily="normal"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:text="00:00"
        android:textColor="#999999"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="6dip"
        android:textColor="#acacac"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#e7e7e7"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp" />



       <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center"/>

       <ListView
           android:id="@+id/commentList"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

But ListView do not scroll down and just shows one element. How to make so that ListView to scroll down?

How it looks:
http://imageshack.com/a/img41/9280/3sk9.jpg

and how i fill the listview:

```
public class ParseComment extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        final String TAG = "ParseComment.java";
        JSONArray dataJsonArr = null;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL+postID);
                dataJsonArr = json.getJSONArray("data");
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    JSONObject c = dataJsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
                    String username = "test";
                    String date = "1396083521";
                    String text = "test";
                    comments.add(new CommentInfo(username, text, date));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String strFromDoInBg) 
        {
          CommentSet();  
        }

    }

    public void CommentSet()
    {
        commentAdapter = new CommentAdapter(this, comments);
        ListView commentList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.commentList);
        commentList.setAdapter(commentAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: why do you have listview with root element as  scrollview. read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Comment: I know English is very bad, ie I need to remove ScrollView?

Comment: You need to remove `ScrollView` because `ListView` has a own implementation for vertical and horizontal scrolling.

Comment: General question is how to arrange the ListView after all elements?